# threejs shader light for texture by color in picture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

Such as the title，I want to add light effect for texture according to the color in the picture.In fact, It's world map with a night light picture texture use three.js, the light in the picture is white, the other place is black. I want add light effect on the white color place, by vertexShader and fragmentShader, GLSL.

The relative ideal effect like the first picture, The second is my test demo.

the perfect effect I want
[image: the perfect effect I want]

my threejs application
[image: my threejs application]

My code is like this:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  vecPos = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
  vecNormal = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(vecPos, 1.0);
}
```

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision highp float;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

uniform float lightIntensity;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

struct PointLight {
  vec3 color;
  vec3 position;
  float distance;
};

uniform PointLight pointLights[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];

void main(void) {
  vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
      vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vecPos - pointLights[l].position);
      addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, vecNormal), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLights[l].color * lightIntensity;
  }
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, vUv) * addedLights;
}
```

Then, the result shown as the following:
[image: the result by the code above]

I fell all the texture is rendered seriously， but the ligth place is so weak and poor, could I judge the color'R G B in the original picture texture and change the coefficient of the gl_FragColor, I failed to do it.

Even though，it may be ugly， because I guess the whole way may be wrong.

Who can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: you want something like this  http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com ?

Comment: To think to cover part of the appearance, it's possible to add dark scene.fog(https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-fog.html) and add several points of light